# Dishwasher holding water

Tags: dishwasher

I have a whirlpool
WDT720PADM2

I cleaned it on Friday and noticed a good amount of water still in the bottom/trap
How normal is it for water to still be there?   Is this an indication of a problem?

After cleaning it yesterday I reran it (1st time since Friday) there was less water collected but about half the trap is full even now a day later it’s still there.

Update:
Snaked out as much I could,
Replaced drain hose,
Blew into drain hose to verify no clog,
Ran dishwasher again - there is still a little bit of water at the bottom of the trap

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Most dishwashers have a float that "tells" the dishwasher if there is water in the basin.

Maybe your **float is stuck** in the down position telling the dishwasher there is no water and no need to pump it out...when in fact there is water.

Comment: Or, possibly, the arm got bent so the float is higher than it should be when the arm is in the "no water left" position. (If the arm/float are visible/accessible.)

Comment: Here's an easy way to tell if this is the problem and to fix it: tap on the side of the float valve several times with the heavy end of a dinner knife.

Answer (score 1):

If you don't have an air gap, you need a high loop in your dishwasher drain hose. Without this, any time you run water down your sink drain, it can find its way into your dishwasher. If you've ever found unexplained suds in your dishwasher, the lack of a high loop or air gap is the cause. Re-arrange your drain hose as shown in the illustration.

[image]

Comment: Thank you but this is the way it is “high loop”

Answer (score 0):

**Air gap clog?**

[image: air gap]
https://structuretech.com/dishwasher-air-gaps/

This happened to me when I had a dishwasher with an air gap.   There was a flexible hose leading to the air gap.  When I took it off it was clearly full of crud -  food from dishes lodged in the air gap hose.  When I cleaned it out it worked again.  Until it clogged again.

https://www.bobvila.com/articles/dishwasher-not-draining/

> Clean your sink’s air gap. When a dishwasher hose connects to a sink
> without a garbage disposal, an air gap—a small, slotted cylinder
> (often made of stainless steel)—is installed on the top of the sink,
> right by the faucet. A small hose from the air gap connects to the
> dishwasher’s drain hose. This acts as a vent to prevent an air lock
> from forming in the drain hose, but occasionally, the air gap can
> become clogged with debris. To investigate, twist the air gap
> counterclockwise to remove it, and check it for gunk. Clean the air
> gap with water and a stiff brush, replace it, and run the dishwasher
> cycle again.

I learned to rinse off dishes before putting them in the dishwasher.  Also now when someone asks why my sink is full of dirty dishes instead of the dishwasher I can explain I am letting them soak to protect the air gap hose.